# Prepend parent node when serializing C# property

Tags: c#, xml

I'd like to serialize the following class to xml:

```
public class Survey
{
    [XmlElement("edit")]
    public string EditLink { get; set; }
}
```

As expected this serializes as (removed extra stuff not important to the question)

```
<Survey><edit>http://example.com/editlink</edit></Survey>
```

However, I'd like to prepend a parent node to the edit node, so that the resultant xml is:

```
<Survey><links><edit>http://example.com/editlink</edit></links></Survey>
```

Is there a way to do this with just the serialization attributes, without modifying the structure of the class?

Comment: you can't magically create an extra element using attributes.you need to change your class structure or use `LINQ to XML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with that structure.  If you expose `EditLink` as a *collection* then you can:

```
public class Survey
{
    [XmlArray("links")]
    [XmlArrayItem("edit")]
    public string[] edit 
    {
        get 
        {
            return new [] {EditLink};
        } 
        set 
        {
            EditLink = value[0];
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string EditLink { get; set; }
}
```

Which yields:

```
<Survey>
    <links>
        <edit>http://example.com/editlink</edit>
    </links>
</Survey>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [XMLSerializer class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10y9yyta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  public class Survey
  {    
      public string EditLink { get; set; }
  }

  private void SerializeSurvey()
  {
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Survey));

     Survey survey = new Survey(){EditLink=""};

     // Create an XmlTextWriter using a FileStream.
     Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
     XmlWriter writer =  new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.Unicode);

     // Serialize using the XmlTextWriter.
     serializer.Serialize(writer, survey);
     writer.Close();
  }
```